# Snort logs in OSSIM show hex in payload but I want only the text to be there. Is there a config I can change in Snort?

Tags: snort

I am new to snort and I am testing things out with OSSIM. I've installed snort and using rsyslog I am getting snort alerts.log to OSSIM. But the thing is payloads of events in OSSIM show as

```
 length = 219

000 : 31 31 2F 32 35 2F 31 39 2D 31 30 3A 30 34 3A 32   11/25/19-10:04:2
010 : 39 2E 37 38 30 31 32 34 20 20 5B 2A 2A 5D 20 5B   9.780124  [**] [
020 : 31 32 30 3A 31 38 3A 33 5D 20 28 68 74 74 70 5F   120:18:3] (http_
030 : 69 6E 73 70 65 63 74 29 20 50 52 4F 54 4F 43 4F   inspect) PROTOCO
040 : 4C 2D 4F 54 48 45 52 20 48 54 54 50 20 73 65 72   L-OTHER HTTP ser
050 : 76 65 72 20 72 65 73 70 6F 6E 73 65 20 62 65 66   ver response bef
060 : 6F 72 65 20 63 6C 69 65 6E 74 20 72 65 71 75 65   ore client reque
070 : 73 74 20 20 5B 2A 2A 5D 20 5B 43 6C 61 73 73 69   st  [**] [Classi
080 : 66 69 63 61 74 69 6F 6E 3A 20 55 6E 6B 6E 6F 77   fication: Unknow
090 : 6E 20 54 72 61 66 66 69 63 5D 20 5B 50 72 69 6F   n Traffic] [Prio
0a0 : 72 69 74 79 3A 20 33 5D 20 7B 54 43 50 7D 20 31   rity: 3] {TCP} 1
0b0 : 39 32 2E 31 36 38 2E 30 2E 31 36 38 3A 38 30 38   92.168.0.168:808
0c0 : 30 20 2D 3E 20 31 39 32 2E 31 36 38 2E 30 2E 31   0 -> 192.168.0.1
0d0 : 32 32 3A 33 39 31 37 30 22 20 0A                  22:39170" .
```

But I want it to be like

```
11/25/19-10:04:29.780124  [**] [120:18:3] (http_inspect) PROTOCOL-OTHER HTTP server response before client request  [**] [Classification: Unknown Traffic] [Priority: 3] {TCP} 192.168.0.168:8080 -> 192.168.0.122:39170" .
```

Is there any config in snort I can change to make this happen?

Thanks in advance for any help!